# Package AceFEM error: cannot be automatically installed

Tags: acegen, opencascade

I have a problem to perform the package AceFEM in Mathematica 12.0.0.0 for Mac (software: macOS Monterey Version 12.4 | processor: 1,8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5). I downloaded the newest AceGen and AceFEM packages from ‘http://symech.fgg.uni-lj.si/Download.htm and started the notebook ‘install.nb’. The installation of both packages was successful. When I am running the command

<<AceGen`;
everything works. But when I am running the command

<<AceFEM`;
it doesn’t work. A screenshot of the occurring error message is in the attachment. I also tried to quit Mathematica and perform the commands again which didn’t work. Does anyone know the solution of this problem?

Thanks in advance and best regards.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly OpencascadeLink was added in version 12.1 and acefem seems to make use of that. Best to update your version of Mathematica. If that's not possible you may be lucky and try to install OpencascadeLink yourself.

https://github.com/WolframResearch/OpenCascadeLink

Comment: Thanks a lot! I updated Mathematica and it is working now.